# we have a Rode Phantom Powered Condenser Shotgun Microphone that is placed near a projector in our media studio

Tags: windscreens

The fan noise tends to get picked up. Any suggestions for a windscreen that we can use? I know nothing about this type of equipment but am trying to help our library recording space better. Someone suggested a wombat or a dead kitten and i honestly can't tell what the difference is between these two items. 
any input is appreciated!!

Comment: Move the mic. A windshield won't prevent noise, only wind.

Comment: Or move the projector

Comment: I WISH we could move the projector. Unfortunately, that is not in the budget. but thank you for the answer about it only preventing wind, rather than noise

Answer (score 1):

Condenser shotgun should be a hypercardiod, there was a technique used when recording leslie cabinets , to put windfilters (the classic black round sponge) to keep the air produced from the horn turning from being recorded by the microphone.

Those microphones can focus pretty good on a sound source, i wonder why you have such a microphone there.

A possible solution used over the years in studios when you care about isolation, is to cut a hole in a paper water cup's bottom , and pass the microphone in it.

That *might* produce some honkyness on the mic's signal so judge the depth by sound quality and isolation.

This answer of course is taken under consideration that you can't move the mic/projector as others have stated before.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I have no idea what you mean by hypercarodiod (isn't that a cardiovascular term?) or who Leslie Cabinets is (just googled, not a person). I will suggest the paper cup solution to the powers that be.

Comment: Cardioid, Hypercardioid, and Supercardioid are the names of some microphone pickup patterns, called as such due to their heart-shaped appearances. Not all microphones pickup sound from all directions, some are designed to only pick up sounds from certain directions with respect to the mic head. - http://sourcedist.tumblr.com/post/2325197924/top-10-tips-for-choosing-a-microphone . Leslie Cabinets are a type of speaker cabinet, with an interesting design - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_speaker